# ios4 photo library path on simulator

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have an app need to load photos from simulator photo library.
After I upgrade ios4, the photo library is empty.
So I have to add the photos manually.
But I can not get the path relates to the photo library on simulator.

Is there anyone know this?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can open a webpage and hold down your mouse to save it

the path in which all the photos saved is:

> /Users/USERNAME/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone Simulator/4.1/Media

`4.1` or which sdk you are using

//EDIT:
I tested it with the first option and it saves all the pictures in `DCIM/100APPLE/` but it also create the folder `PhotoData/100APPLE/` where for each picture a `.BTH` and `.THM` is saved.
So the easiest way is to drag and drop a image on the simulator. The Simulator will open a webpage to your local file (`"file://…"`) and then you can save it but holding your mouse key for 3 seconds or so.
Then click "save image" and it should appear in your Photo Library.

Comment: Thanks. But even I add photos the that directory in Finder, when I run 'photo' app on simulator, there still is nothing

Comment: there is a DCIM and PhotoData/MISC subfolder I don't know which is the right you must test both

Answer (score 0):

I find this free app very useful to batch import pictures into the simulator:

http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/09/importing-photos/

If it doesn't work straight away, follow the Reset Content instructions (warning - this will completely reset all apps and data on the simulator), and as long as you have a photo in the Photos app before you do it, it does work well.